# rails not picking up new image in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running into a strange issue. If i add a new image to the images folder and use it on a web page - rails is throwing an error like this.

```
    Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( spinner60.gif ) to config/initializers/assets.rb and restart your server
```

This is all happening in development mode only. I am developing locally - and not on any server production or otherwise.

If i reboot the server on local machine - rails picks up the asset and serves it without any complains.

Anybody experience anything like this before? - No changes made to any of the environment or asset files.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
asset.rb =  
    # Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
    # Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

    # Add additional assets to the asset load path
    # Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

    # Precompile additional assets.
    # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
    # Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

and development.rb = 

        Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  # config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Comment: Have you add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( spinner60.gif )` into the assets.rb file and restart your localhost?

Comment: Hi Zulhilmi - thank for replying to the question. But I dont think i should have to do that. I have never had to add assets individually to the asset pipeline individually. Rails is supposed to pick up everything in assets folder and its subs. It is not happening in this case - ergo the question.

Comment: You might have played with this setting: `config.assets.compile = true`

Comment: You might have executed `rake assets:precompile` in the development environment. If so, delete all generated assets.